# Update calculated answer

Tags: python

i have some data get from arduino and need to using kmeans to calulating answer. How can keep update the calcution result and shown in shell.

```
import kmeans1d
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',4800)
r1=ser.readline()
# x = [400, 150, 150, 130, 140] sample data from arduino it's will keep change
x = r1.decode('utf8').rstrip().split(", ")
for i in range(0, len(x)): 
    x[i] = int(x[i])
k = 2
clusters, centroids = kmeans1d.cluster(x, k)
print(clusters)   # [1, 0, 0, 0, 0] how can keep updating result
```

the output should like this

```
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
    ....
```

Comment: What do you mean with "keep calculate"? Doing everything again? In this case, use a loop.

Comment: as the data will be changing, so the answer will also changing. i want to monitor the result in shell and no need to press the run button on Thonny.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want to go back to the beginning (`ser = ...`) and do it all over again? Add a loop around everything. Maybe sleeping in between, maybe checking if the data actually changed.

Comment: Like this?

`test = [
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',4800)
……
print(clusters)   # [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
for x in test:
    print(x)
time.sleep(1)`

Comment: No... Just a simple loop around everything... where does `test = [...]` come from? I think I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve and how the output should look like.

Comment: `fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
for x in fruits:
  print(x)` i am using this for reference...but it will shown error :(....I also updated the result I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest putting a loop around and let it run:

```
import kmeans1d
import serial
import time

while True:
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',4800)
    r1=ser.readline()
    # x = [400, 150, 150, 130, 140] sample data from arduino it's will keep change
    x = r1.decode('utf8').rstrip().split(", ")
    for i in range(0, len(x)): 
        x[i] = int(x[i])
    k = 2
    clusters, centroids = kmeans1d.cluster(x, k)
    print(clusters)   # [1, 0, 0, 0, 0] how can keep updating result
    time.sleep(1) # sleep one second before trying again
```

This code will run forever. Alternatively, if you just want to run it for defined amount of runs, replace the while loop with a for loop. The sleeping is just there so it doesn't spam the console too much without new data, as I don't know if `ser.readline()` blocks until there is new data.

I'm not 100% sure if it is really needed to create a new Serial all the time, maybe it could be put outside the loop.

Comment: It's work!!!! you are right, ser.readline() will block to caluteing the result, sometime it can not get fully data. but i had change time.sleep form 1 to 0.5, it's look better.

Comment: If it's blocking and you're interested in everything, you might also remove time.sleep(). Just put it there because I didn't know. If my answer helped you, please don't forget to accept ;)